# Include formula field in Crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to include my long formula field in a column of my crosstab. But I don't see it as selectable in the crosstab setup screen. How can I include it?

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar i:=Sum({@multiplying_records});
NumberVar t:=i/Sum({%assigning_credit});
t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can't. But there is a workaround.

Your Running Total field is evaluated during the *Printing* phase, but Crosstabs populate during the *Reading* phase. So your Running Total won't be ready by the time the Crosstab needs it to be.

---

The best way around this is to perform the running total's calculations in a custom SQL statement. You can add this from the Database Expert and have SQL do the math for you:

[image]

This will return a new table in which you can calculate your RT as a field even before it reaches the report. Which means it exists during the Reading phase can be used in a Crosstab.

Comment: in the add command window the is a parameter box and a sql query box. How should i write sql query here?

Comment: @Ishti You pretty much hit the nail on the head: Type your SQL Query in that box; add parameters as necessary; hit `Create`.  (You'll also need to go to Database Expert -> Links and hook it up to your existing tables as appropriate.)